# Received a check in the mail, realized a day after depositing it that it was a fake

Tags: scams, check, fraud

About a week and a half ago, I received a check in the mail. I stupidly deposited it and contact my bank, the fraud department and signed papers a day after doing so. I am receiving few answers from anyone as to what is going on and this has never happened to me before. I do have a photo of the check from my bank from when I deposited it. Since then the check has “chargedback” whatever that means. I’ve read that it means that it has bounced, and I’ve read other things. Which is good, because I do not want the money in my account. I’ve also tried to research where the check came from and I’ve been able to verify that the check is written from a real account and routing number, but the bank did verify that I was correct, that it was a fake check. Any advice?

Comment: A more concise question would be easier to answer. Were you expecting a check in the mail? Or did you get one out of the blue and just deposited it without question?

Comment: And was it a personal check from a friend, from a stranger, or was it a business check?

Comment: I am not sure who it was from. If I did, I would have reported them. I have a photo of the check that the bank put on my deposit record and all I’ve been able to find is that the account and routing are real, but that the check, as I suspected AFTER depositing it (stupid of me) was fake. It did appear to be a business check.

Answer (score 6):

> Since then the check has “chargedback” whatever that means. I’ve read
> that it means that it has bounced

Usually when you deposit a check the bank credits the funds immediately, before the money is actually transferred. If there is no real money (i.e., the check is fake), then the bank will take back the money. This sounds like an attempted [fake check scam](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/how-spot-avoid-and-report-fake-check-scams). This scam is well documented, so Google if you want more info.

As for your situation, I think you can move on. You reported the check and the money is no longer in your account. If anyone contacts you regarding this check then ignore them. Most likely they are trying to scam you.